# Getting data in EntityFramework filtered by string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, model-view-controller, automapper

I have the string I'm not sure how to match it to the data in the database.

I use Automapper which requires an int to use Find(id), because I am passing in a string I can't do this as it throws an error (which makes sense as the string is not a PK or FK).

My question is_  how do I tell my function to take this string that I've passed in and find the matching entry in the database and return the results?  I've included my code below.

Method

```
    public FixtureViewModel ChartererModal(string id)
    {
        var fixtures = db.tbl_vessel_fixtures.Find(id);
        var vm = Mapper.Map<FixtureViewModel>(fixtures);            
        return vm
    }
```

Comment: Serious question: Why do you use find, why do you use MAP. GIven you use AutoMapper you should be able to use ProjectTo, which would allow you do to a SELECT on the FictureViewModel if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
public ActionResult ChartererModal(string id)
{
    int intValue;
    bool parsed = Int32.TryParse(id, out intValue);

    if (!parsed)
        throw new Exception("Error during parsing string to integer");

    var fixtures = db.tbl_vessel_fixtures.Find(intValue);
    var vm = Mapper.Map<FixtureViewModel>(fixtures);            
    return PartialView("_ChartererDetails", vm);
}
```

Or you can try to change method signature to accept integers, like:

```
public ActionResult ChartererModal(int id)
{
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try Parsing the string to an int:

```
int numberid = Int32.Parse(id);
var fixtures = db.tbl_vessel_fixtures.Find(numberid);
```

As long as your string input is a number your fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `id` parameter actually *is* the ID of your object, simply change the parameter type to `int`:

```
public ActionResult ChartererModal(int id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string (id) is not a PK, you can use a Linq-query to retrieve you fixtures-entity:

```
db.tbl_vessel_fixtures.FirstOrDefault(vf => vf.<property name> == id)
```

This is, of course, when the id-string can be found in a proprty of the tbl_vessel_fixtures entity and db is a DbContext, and tbl_vessel_fixtures is a DbSet of your DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

use where clause of linq to find records for matching string syntax would be look like

Collection.Where(x => x.Name == "Fido")